# Are you able to use vue.js inside an ejs file?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ejs

Sorry guys I am new to node.js and was wondering whether we are allowed to use vue.js within an ejs file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `VueJS` can be implemented into existing systems, you should be able to do so yes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we can. Here is a scenario. Let's say you want to render a `data` Object to ejs file, and you want this `data` Object be accessible from VueJS. 
First, in your controller, you have to render it as a JSON string
`res.render("index", { data: JSON.stringify(data) });` in order to access it in your javascript code.
Then, in your VueJS code inside ejs file, you simply access it this way:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        myData: JSON.parse('<%- data %>')
    }
})
```

Note about `<%-` tag in your VueJS code, it is necessary in order to output your data properly.

Comment: i'm having a problem where JSON.parse() is giving back undefined. I am, however, getting a value if I console log some raw data. `{"message":"Welcome to the API.","version":"1.0.0","title":"API"}`

Comment: What data type did you console log? JSON string or JS Object?